# How do the salt argument and return value for PHP's crypt() function work?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography

Normally if I have a password, I would use this pseudocode:

```
$password = "this is the user's password";
/***/
$salt = GenerateSalt();
$hash = Hash($password);
$hash = Hash($hash . $salt);
```

However, as I understand it, PHP has a `crypt()` function which takes a salt as well as the number of iterations of a particular algorithm. Apparently you are.. supposed to pass the returned hash of `crypt` *back into* `crypt` as the salt. I do not understand this.

Can anyone please clarify how crypt works? Do I still need to append my own salt and rehash? In that case, would I just use a fixed salt for crypt, and then generate a separate crypt for each user? Or does crypt's `$salt` parameter take care of that for me?

Comment: Please be aware that you should *PHP's [`crypt`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is not suitable to use prior to version 5.3*.  You *always* want to use the `$2a$`, `$5$` or `$6$` prefixes to get Blowfish, SHA-256 or SHA-512 respectively, and those are not guaranteed to be available in earlier versions.  Please read the manual page for more details.

Comment: Also be aware that crypt is broken in PHP 5.3.7 for MD5.  They've just released the bugfix 5.3.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `crypt` consists of:

- (optionally an algorithm identifier + load factor)
- the salt for the used algorithm
- the real hash

When you pass this output als "salt" back to `crypt`, it will extract the right algorithm and salt, and use these for the operation. If there is only an algorithm mentioned, it uses this one and generate random salt. Otherwise it will choose a default algorithm and generate random salt. The `hash` part in the passed salt parameter is ignored.

So you can simply compare your stored_hash with crypt(password, stored_hash) - if it is equal, it quite likely was the right password.

Here is an pseudocode explanation (in PHP-like syntax) how crypt works:

```
function crypt($password, $salt)
{
  if (substr($salt,0 1) == "_") {
     $count = substr($salt, 1, 4);
     $real_salt = substr($salt, 5, 4);
     return "_" . $count . $real_salt . crypt_ext_des($password, $count, $salt);
  }
  if(substr($salt, 0, 3) == "$1$") {
     list($ignored, $real_salt, $ignored) = explode("$", $salt);
     return "$1$" . $real_salt . "$" . crypt_md5($password, $real_salt);
  }
  if(substr($salt, 0, 4) == "$2a$") {
      $cost = substr($salt, 4, 2);
      $real_salt = substr($salt, 7, 22);
      return "$2a$" . $cost . "$" . $real_salt . crypt_brypt($password, $real_salt, $cost);
  }
  // ... SHA256 and SHA512 analogons

  // no match => STD_DES
  $real_salt = substr($salt, 0, 2);
  return $real_salt . crypt_std_des($password, $real_salt);
}
```

The individual crypt_xxx functions then do the real work, depending on the algorithm.
(Actually, the generation of random salt is missing in this description. It will be done if the $real_salt is empty.)

Comment: So the "hash" returned is actually both a salt and a hash, and typically in say a MySQL database I would just store this as one value?

Comment: All of algorithm identifier, salt and hash. And yes, you would store the whole return value in the database as one varchar value.

Answer (score 0):

crypt is one-way hashing, like MD5

Use it like stated in manual

```
<?php
$password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated

/* You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing a
   password, to avoid problems when different hashing algorithms are used. (As
   it says above, standard DES-based password hashing uses a 2-character salt,
   but MD5-based hashing uses 12.) */
if (crypt($user_input, $password) == $password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
?>
```

Comment: That was my question exactly. `if (crypt($user_input, $password) == $password)` doesn't really make sense to me. Why are you passing `$password`, which was the hash, as the salt?

Comment: crypt('mypassword') creates salt, not a password.